# fedora 21 tigervnc resolution settings

Tags: linux, resolution, vnc, xrandr, fedora-21

I'm using fedora 21 remotely from Win7 remote desktop client.
But the tigervnc screen resolution size is not properly set automatically.
So I have to enter the following command every time after the gnome3 session begins.

xrandr --output VNC-0 --mode 1280x1024

I want to run this command automatically every time when gnome session begins.
How can I do this?
By the way my current ".vnc/xstartup" is like following.

$ cat $HOME/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I searched over the web and found the information about this.
So, I tried the following.
And it seems working.

1)
Make a *.desktop file under the .config/autostart/ directory.

$ vi $HOME/.config/autostart/xrandr-startup.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=xrandr-startup
GenericName=xrandr-startup
Comment=Start these up at login
Exec=/usr/local/bin/xrandr-startup.sh
Terminal=False
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

2)
Make a shell script which runs xrandr command.

# vi /usr/local/bin/xrandr-startup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output VNC-0 --mode 1280x1024
```

# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xrandr-startup.sh

But some times, following dialog displayed before login.

```
+--------------------------
| Authentification Required
| Authentification is required to create a color managed device
| Password: [   ]
+--------------------------
```

I'm not sure how to avoid this.